# clearcase issues with default.magic file - not visible in Win7

Tags: windows-7, clearcase

I'm having some issues with my `default.magic` file in clearcase when adding files to clearcase.

When I go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\config\magic` the `default.magic` file is not visible in windows explorer or by doing a `dir` in a `cmd` window.

However I can open the file in a text editor and make changes to it. (Via the open dialog).

What is going on? Is it possible clearcase can't find its own file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why the [`default.magic` file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cc.magic.htm?resultof=%22magic.file%22%20), wouldn't be visible, but it is best to leave that *default* file untouched.

As explained in [Evaluating multiple magic files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21219216), you can define multiple magic files for you to test.

In "[About the ClearCase Magic file](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122471)", you would, for Windows (including CC7.1+) create a **`cc.magic`** file (in the same directory as the `default.magic` file). And that file would be visible enough.